# Junit error when run from Eclipse after upgrading to Kepler SR1

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, eclipse-kepler

After updating my Eclipse Kepler to SR1, I can't run my junit tests anymore from Eclipse.

After starting up Eclipse, I see this error message in the logs:

```
Variable references empty selection: ${project_loc}
```

When selecting a test case, and Run As, Junit Test, I'm getting this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching DrillUtilTest".
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualResource.getProjectRelativePaths(VirtualResource.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.resources.VirtualFile.getUnderlyingFiles(VirtualFile.java:104)
    ...
```

So maybe the ${project_loc} variable is empty somehow, but it is not used in any of my Junit run configurations. I've tried starting Junit in various ways, but they all give the same result. Before upgrading to SR1, this used to work fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This problem is also wreaking havoc to my maven build. I can't build my project anymore, whooaa!

Answer (score 0):

Each Eclipse project contain a pre-defined set of path variables available for defining linked resources, including ECLIPSE_HOME, PARENT_LOC, PROJECT_LOC and WORKSPACE_LOC

If you right click on your project and choose Properties, then go to Resource > Linked Resource, do you see these variables listed?

Comment: Yes, I see them. They seem to be fine.